# Why use association in sequelize orm?

Tags: node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I made some api system with nodejs.

Also I use sequelize(version 4) for communicates with MySQL.

Below is my model structure.

[user]

- no(PK)
- userid
- userpw

[article]

- no(PK)
- subject
- content
- writer(FK to user's `userid`)

I made with sequelize orm define like this.

```
import Sequelize from 'sequelize';

const sequelize = new Sequelize('db', 'user', 'pw', {
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    dialect: 'mysql'
})

const User = sequelize.define('user', {
    no: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    userid: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(30),
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true
    },
    userpw: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(30),
        allowNull: false
    }
}, {
    freezeTableName: true,
    timestamps: true,
    underscored: true
});

const Article = sequelize.define('article', {
    no: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    subject: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(50),
        allowNull: false
    },
    content: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(100),
        allowNull: false
    },
    writer: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(30),
        references: {
            model: 'user',
            key: 'userid'
        }
    }
}, {
    freezeTableName: true,
    timestamps: true,
    underscored: true
})

sequelize.sync({
    force: true
});

export default { User, Article };
```

In `Article` model, I define write and refer to `User`'s userid.

So `Article`'s writer column is Foreign Key refer to `User`'s userid.

Because If user was deleted, related article have to delete.

Run that code, table will be created and structure is like this.

```
mysql> desc user;
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| no         | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| userid     | varchar(30) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| userpw     | varchar(30) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at | datetime    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at | datetime    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> desc article;
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| no         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| subject    | varchar(50)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| content    | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| writer     | varchar(30)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| created_at | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| updated_at | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

After do that, I searched more information about association in sequelize orm.

And I found that sequelize has many association like `hasMany`, `BelongsTo`, 'hasMany`, ...

So I add `User.hasMany(Article);` to my previous code and run it, it add more columns.

```
mysql> desc article;
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| no         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| subject    | varchar(50)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| content    | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| writer     | varchar(30)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| created_at | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| updated_at | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| user_no    | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

`user_no` column was added.

I think it automatically added by `hasMany` function.

But in my case, I do not have to create `user_no`, Because I already refer to `User`'s `user_id` column.

Overall, my question is:

1. I think I do not have to set `hasMany` in my case. Is it right?
2. Why ORM offer assocation function? Just for convenience? or Is there any reason for it?

Thanks.